# Node: Applying express middleware to specific GraphQL query types

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have multiple `graphql` query types. I wish to apply middleware to one query type only for authentication. Is this possible?

Something like this

```js
app.use(
 '/s',
 (request, response, next) => {
  if (request.body.message === 'delete') {
   auth();
  }

  next();
 },
 graphqlHTTP({
  schema: require('./r/s').schema(),
  graphiql: true,
 })
);
```

The issue is that the format of the body is not JSON.

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with "Query Types" because a schema only has one query type. Maybe you mean query fields. You can run a parser on the values in the body, but I think, thinking in middleware is not very helpful. There is https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware, which is middleware specificly for fields. Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, actually you can accomplish that by using graphql-middleware library.

you just define the middleware and then attach it to a specific Query or Mutation.
a grqphql middleware works as a resolver, it takes: parent, args, context, info and in addition to those it also takes "resolve" which is a function we call when the middleware finishes, pretty much like "next()" in express.

```
asycn function checkIfUserLoggedIn(resolve, parent, args, context, info){
    // check if user logged in or not

   // now we call resolve and pass the arguments to the resolver which is in our case "getSecret" Query
return resolve(parent, args, context, info)
}

const middlewares = {
  Query: {
    getSecret: checkIfUserLoggedIn,
  },
};

const schemaWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  schema,
 ...middlewares
)
```

and then you edit your graphqlHTTP to:

```
graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schemaWithMiddleware,
  graphiql: true,
 })
```